# Get File inside a folder with getFilesAsync and getFoldersAsync

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, runtime

Having this

```
public IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList;
```

and do this with it

```
folderList = await musicFolder.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);
```

I should have all folders inside Music folder (musicFolder is knownfolders.musiclibrary)

but when inside a cicle i try to do

```
for (int i=0; i<folderList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (folderList[i].Name==(lbMusic_Albums.SelectedItem as songStruct).songName)
                        {

                            StorageFolder current = folderList[i];

                            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> TempFileList = await current.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName); //OTHER CODE
```

I get on the await line system argument exception.. I do not understand why, Am i passing it correctly?

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery query)
>      at DUS.MainPage.d__31.MoveNext()

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Sorry i've forgotten to copy that part:

System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery query)
   at DUS.MainPage.<select>d__31.MoveNext()

Comment: So any news? please i'm stuck

Comment: I don't know; I've never used these APIs.

Comment: do you know other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way :D

```
FolderLib = await musicFolder.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);
//Obtaining all the folders and do for every folder this


 foreach(StorageFolder item in FolderLib)
 {  // Take the subfolder
     SubFolderlib = await item.GetFilesAsync();
    // and do stuff with it
 }
```

FolderLib and SubFolderLib were

```
public IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> SubFolderlib;

public IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> FolderLib;
```